# Maximum price for calling inside the EU, from when?

Tags: cellphones, eu

Last year, the [EU agreed to cap prices of international phone calls](https://www.euractiv.com/section/digital/news/eu-caps-price-of-international-phone-calls-in-landmark-telecoms-overhaul/):

> The European Parliament scored a victory after months of heated negotiations as the European Commission and national diplomats agreed to limit the price of phone calls between EU countries to 19 cents per minute. Text messages will be capped at 6 cents per SMS for consumers within the bloc.

Is this final yet?  From when will it be effective?  My provider still charges €1.49/minute for calls to another EU country (as of 8 May 2019).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new price regulations will take effect on [May 15th, 2019](https://www.euractiv.com/section/digital/news/calling-within-europe-will-be-cheaper-from-may-2019/).

For completeness of the answer, the legal basis is Regulation (EU) 2018/1971, which added a new article 5a to Regulation (EU) 2015/2120:

> Article 5a
>
> Retail charges for regulated intra-EU communications
>
> 1. From 15 May 2019, any retail price (excluding VAT) charged to consumers for regulated intra-EU communications shall not exceed EUR
>      0,19 per minute for calls and EUR 0,06 per SMS message.

Comment: The article says May 1 in the first paragraph and May 15 in the fifth?

Comment: @NateEldredge Either my provider violates the regulations or it has not taken effect yet on May 1.

Comment: @gerrit   Price caps will come into effect on 15 May 2019. Source: http://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/press-room/20181106IPR18320/meps-cap-prices-of-calls-within-eu-and-approve-emergency-alert-system

Comment: I just confirmed that my provider has not yet implemented this, and the contact person I reached has no knowledge of any plans of upcoming price changes.  They're still charging €1,49/minute a week before the deadline.  We shall see.

Comment: Alas, my provider (Congstar) still charges €1.49/minute.

Comment: @gerrit In Germany, the new EU regulation has not yet been implemented in national law.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Aha, that would explain.  Where do you find that information?

Comment: @gerrit By using Google. More accurately: the regulation is 'as is' in effect in Germany, but there are no penalties for companies violating the regulation, as these are set in national law. Penalties for violating the cost limits set in the regulation are included in 6. TKGÄndG, which is currently stuck somewhere in the slow-grinding mills of German politics: https://www.bmwi.de/Redaktion/DE/Artikel/Service/Gesetzesvorhaben/sechste-aenderung-telekommunikationsgesetz-tkg.html

Comment: Looks like [they lowered it to €0.22/minute](https://www.congstar.de/fileadmin/files_congstar/documents/2019/Preislisten/Preisliste_congstar_Prepaid.pdf) as of 2019-12-12.